# How to set password of cups 1.3.7 (/etc/cups/passwd.md5) without prompting?

Tags: authentication, cups

My company is using CUPS v1.3.7, I would like to allow users to be authenticated only in the cups web interface and not via SSH.

I imagine, i should use the authentication type `BasicDigest` in cupsd.conf.

```
AuthType Digest
```

Then i have to use `lppasswd -g mygroup -a username` to add the access to cups to the user.

```
lppasswd -g mygroup -a username
Enter password :
Enter password again :
```

But, if i allow my user to type some password, i would allow them to access ssh, what i do not want to.

How can I set the password of a user without prompting (possibly scripting it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way of thinking on this matter: Restrict ssh access to specific groups.

- Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Add the line `AllowGroups sshusers` or `AllowGroups your_user_primary_group`

  - In case of `AllowGroups sshusers` create this administrative group: `groupadd -r sshusers`
  - Add ssh allowed users to this group:  `usermod -aG sshusers username`
- Reload sshd service. Depends on your distro.

Using this solution you will not have to script Cups user creation, neither manage 2 distincts login databases.

Comment: Yes, that look MUCH more simpler!